# Android app opens all http links

Tags: android, url-scheme

I add two url schemes to manifest:

```
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="appinsider.mobile/"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="appinsiderlink/"
                android:scheme="http" />

        </intent-filter>
```

But apart from these URL, the application opens all links starting with "http"
How to open only links declared in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `android:host="appinsiderlink/"` tag needs to be a valid URI host (e.g., `google.com`). It probably also shouldn't have a trailing slash.

You're also setting `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">`, but haven't mentioned if you also took the steps necessary to [declare website associations](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc)...